# Eclipse build errors when using Gradle or Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle

When using a build manager like Gradle or Maven, my dependencies are being managed correctly, however the Eclipse IDE is unaware of the resolved dependencies so it will still show errors and I cannot build through Eclipse, I have to run a 'build' command through the build manager.

How do you get Eclipse to be aware of the resolved dependencies taken care of by a build manager and running the app through the IDE?

Comment: If you are using Maven, do you install m2e plugin for eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate Eclipse metadata using eclipse plugin distribute with Gradle - http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html - this will set up the project with its classpath.

Or install Gradle plugin for Eclipse developed by Pivotal folks.

Comment: using `gradle eclipse` will actually lead to situation when after making changes in `build.gradle` project will build with command line, but would have errors in Eclipse (With Gradle EP by Pivotal).

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague. Using m2e or Gradle plugin for Eclipse developed by Pivotal can lead you to different errors. You should ask exact question, sharing error that you got here on stackoverflow.